# Overcoming the race condition in lock-free reference-counted dereferences

Tags: race-condition, lock-free, reference-counting

Imagine a structure like this:

```
struct my_struct {
    uint32_t refs
    ...
}
```

for which a pointer is acquired through a lookup table:

```
struct my_struct** table;

my_struct* my_struct_lookup(const char* name)
{
    my_struct* s = table[hash(name)];

    /* EDIT: Race condition here. */

    atomic_inc(&s->refs);

    return s;
}
```

A race exists between the dereference and the atomic increment in a multi-threaded model. Given that this is very performance critical code, I was wondering how this race inbetween the dereference and atomic increment is typically resolved or worked around?

EDIT: When acquiring a pointer to a `my_struct` structure via the lookup table, it is necessary to first dereference the structure in order to increment its reference count. This creates a problem in multi-threaded code when other threads could be altering the reference count and potentially deallocating the object itself while another thread would then dereference a pointer to non-existent memory. Combined with preemption and some bad luck, this could be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  it is not apparent to me what the race is between.

Comment: Ah.  You're deallocating the structs - that wasn't apparent in the OP.

Comment: Did you try embedding more parameters in an 8 byte struct and atomically manipulating the struct with 64 bit operations?  See my answer.

Comment: @johnnycrash I've decided to base my solution on yours as it requires the least code and bookkeeping. I've also made some changes which significantly reduce the number of lookups that have to be made and I'm happy with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said above, you can make linked list of memory to free at some later time, so your pointers are never invalid.  This is a handy method in some cases.

Or....you can make a 64 bit struct with your 32 bit pointer and have 32 bits for a ref count and other flags.  You can use 64 bit atomic ops on the struct if you wrap it in a union:

```
union my_struct_ref {
    struct { 
      unsigned int       cUse     : 16,
                         fDeleted : 1;    // etc 
      struct my_struct  *s;
    } Data;
    unsigned long n64;
}
```

You can human readably work with the Data part of the struct, and you can use CAS on the n64 bit part.

```
my_struct* my_struct_lookup(const char* name)
{
    struct my_struct_ref Old, New;
    int iHash = hash(name);

    // concurrency loop
    while (1) {
      Old.n64 = table[iHash].n64;
      if (Old.Data.fDeleted)
        return NULL;
      New.n64 = Old.n64;
      New.Data.cRef++;
      if (CAS(&table[iHash].n64, Old.n64, New.n64)) // CAS = atomic compare and swap
        return New.Data.s; // success
      // we get here if some other thread changed the count or deleted our pointer
      // in between when we got a copy of it int old.  Just loop to try again.
    } 
}
```

If you are using 64 bit pointers you will need to do 128 bit CAS.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a freelist, rather than malloc() and free().  This has obvious drawbacks.

Another is to implement lock-free garbage collection (also known as Safe Memory Reclaimation).

There are MANY patents in this field, but it appears that epoch-based LFGC is unencumbered.

The upshot of using this method is that elements are only deallocated when no threads are pointing at them.

The former solution is very easy to implement.  You need a lock-free freelist, of course, or your overall system is no longer lock-free.

The latter is really not complex, but requires learning the algorithm in question, which takes some time and research.

Comment: I actually had something like a freelist in mind at first, or something else that could allow me to defer the reclaim until later since I use a multiversion concurrency control-like approach. So these are solid suggestions, thanks! I'd do anything to do less bookkeeping though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the race you identified, you have a general problem of **memory consistency**.

Even if you could make the table modifications atomic in a lock-free fashion, the block of memory `my_struct*` points to could still be "stale" when seen from a different thread compared to the thread that last modified it. This does not apply to `my_struct.refs` (provided you *always* access it using atomics), but does apply to all other fields. This is the consequence of write buffers and caches that are "private" to each CPU core.

The only way to guarantee you are seeing the correct memory content is to use a memory barrier. Yet, a typical lock is *also* a memory barrier, so why not just use the lock in the first place?

Lock-free programming is much trickier than may initially seem, OTOH locks can be very fast, especially when contentions are rare. Have you actually benchmarked lock-based implementation and confirmed that locking is indeed your bottleneck?

Comment: I'm currently reading about the internals of cache-coherency in modern processors for the memory consistency you are talking about. This task is overwhelming, but worthwhile since the code is being called _a lot_. Thank you for the concern though.